# css in codeigniter

Tags: css, .htaccess, codeigniter, text, view

Hi i have such a problem in codeigniter. I cant use styles of my .css file. But I know that this filt is connected to my views. (Firebug). Here is my link for connecting:

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/Enlighten.css" type="text/css" />`
```

css file in directory `/images/Enlighten.css`

Here is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|template|robots\.txt|public|)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css¦js¦jpg¦gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think that my mistake is in this file.(I dont deal in this file :((  )

P.S Everywhere when i use styles from Enlighten.css text print as '??????????'

Comment: Sorry I have marked text as code, because site cant differ code out of text

Comment: No worries. I fixed that for you. For code you can use 4 spaces instead of `

Answer (score 3):

How about making it less complicated like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

ps.
It's best not to place your CSS in the images directory to prevent confusion.
I always use an assets folder and organize everything in there:

```
/Assets
  /css
  /images
  /js
```

Comment: I have moved .css file to the local directory. Rewrite the link and css rules works. But '?????' is stayed. See: http://s42.radikal.ru/i098/1208/f4/6c3d5990b784.jpg

Comment: It seems to be an encoding issue. Can you open the file directly like site.com/Enlighten.css?

Comment: Yes, I can. But if it encoding, why do all another text is normally?

Comment: Can you show us some of your html & css? You can use jsfiddle.net for that.

Comment: I assume the text is in Russian? Try changing utf-8 to KOI8-R in  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset= utf-8" />

Answer (score 1):

use following code for your htaccess file :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you're missing a line here Rakesh. This way everything will be redirected to index.php, including the CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the following `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Prevents user access to the application folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: IMHO it's unneccesary to restrics access here since the folders already have their own `.htaccess` files that prevent anyone from accessing them.

Comment: @Robert Why to choke file system with unnecessary files like empty `index.html` or `.htaccess`?

Comment: so you don't have to have to place everything in one file and maintain it when you rename a folder for instance.

Comment: @Robert But that's just general access permissions. I think, it is easier to check which files and directories are public in one `.htaccess` file, instead of checking all the files in each and every sub directory. Maybe, that's just my personal preference. :)